# How to stub Vue component methods for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, sinon

How can I stub certain methods (getters, in particular) from Vue single file components for unit testing with mocha/expect?

The problem I was facing was the following: 
I have a component with a get method *someData*

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import SomeService from '@/services/some.service'

@Component()
export default class MyApp extends Vue {
    ...

    mounted () {
      ...
    }

    get someData () {
      return this.$route.path.split('/')[1] || 'main'
    }

    get getLocation () {
      return this.someService.getBaseURL()
    }

    initSomeStringProperty (): string {
      return 'some string'
    }
}
</script>
```

My tests always fail with:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

When I try to stub the method using sinon, like following:

```
describe('MyApp.vue', () => {
  if('returns main', () => {
    const dataStub = sinon.stub(MyApp, 'someData')
    listStub.yields(undefined, 'main')
    const wrapper = shallowMount(AppNavBar)
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include('Some Content')
  })
})
```

However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property someData

In addition, I get the same error for every other method, I want to stub analogously, e.g., initSomeStringProperty().

Comment: It is a vue-class-component. Please find the exemplary code in the edited question above.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above `someData` is computed property that is defined with property accessor through `vue-property-decorator`.

It can be stubbed at two points, either on class prototype:

```
sinon.stub(MyApp.prototype, 'someData').get(() => 'foo');
```

Or component options:

```
sinon.stub(MyApp.options.computed.someData, 'get').value('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the component's [computed props and methods upon mounting](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#other-options), as shown below. ***Update: As of 1.x, setting methods has been [deprecated](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/upgrading-to-v1/#setmethods-and-mountingoptions-methods) in favor of stubbing (see [@EstusFlask's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151372/6277151) on how to properly stub with Sinon).***

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyApp, {
  computed: {
    someData: () => 'foo'
  },
  methods: {
    initSomeStringProperty: () => 'bar'
  }
})
expect(wrapper.vm.someData).to.equal('foo')
expect(wrapper.vm.initSomeStringProperty()).to.equal('bar')
```

If you were just trying to avoid the error about `$route` being undefined, you could [mock `$route` upon mounting](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#mocks):

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyApp, {
  mocks: {
    $route: { path: '/home' }
  }
})
expect(wrapper.vm.someData).to.equal('home')
```

Comment: "overwriting methods via the `methods` property is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. There is no clear migration path for the `methods` property - Vue does not support arbitrarily replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex method extract it from the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests."

Comment: @VongarnichtsundStuff Added note about deprecation

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3, you can stub the component itself before using `mount` or `shallowMount`:

```
sinon.stub(YourComponentName.methods, 'yourMethodName');
```